# proteger mis rutas - me imprime mi Json

Tags: php, laravel, json, laravel-5, vue.js

Estoy tratando de evitar imprimir mi formato Json directamente(o no sé  si haya alguna u otra forma)

lo que pasa es que  cuando accedo a mi ruta de esta forma

```
http://blissre.test/projects/
```

me carga mis proyectos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí todo bien, cuando carga la pagina projects. axios hace el resto extrae mi información  que tengo  en mi BD  y voy imprimiendo con vue.Js

```html
getLista:function(){

 var url = '/projects/';

 axios.get(url).then(response=>{
  
  this.listaPro=response.data

 }).catch(error =>{
  
  console.log(error.data);
  miEstilo();
  
  toastr.error('Error al obtener proyectos');
 });
},
```

Excelente todo bien

mi controlador lo tengo de esta forma

```html
 public function index()
    {
        //

       return view('proyectos.index');


    }
```

lo cual me muestra esa ruta.

pero cuando acceso a mi ruta de esta forma, me carga todo mi Json en la pagina, habrá alguna forma de poder evitar mostrar esa información?

```
http://blissre.test/projects/index
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
[
{
"id": 4,
"titulo": "soy 2",
"antecedentes": "2",
"problematica": "2",
"justificacion": "2",
"objetivoG": "2",
"objetivoE": "2",
"tags": "2",
"status": 0,
"user_id": 1,
"profe_id": null,
"created_at": "2018-03-30 15:29:10",
"updated_at": "2018-03-30 15:29:10"
},
{
"id": 8,
"titulo": "soy 8",
"antecedentes": "gfg",
"problematica": "gfd",
"justificacion": "gdfgfg",
"objetivoG": "dfg",
"objetivoE": "dfgdff",
"tags": "gdfg",
"status": 0,
"user_id": 1,
"profe_id": null,
"created_at": "2018-03-30 16:13:26",
"updated_at": "2018-03-30 16:13:26"
},
{
"id": 9,
"titulo": "sou 9",
"antecedentes": "999",
"problematica": "jkjdsds",
"justificacion": "9999",
"objetivoG": "999999999",
"objetivoE": "99999",
"tags": "99999",
"status": 0,
"user_id": 1,
"profe_id": null,
"created_at": "2018-03-30 16:14:02",
"updated_at": "2018-03-30 16:14:02"
},
{
"id": 10,
"titulo": "soy 10",
"antecedentes": "lkjl",
"problematica": "10",
"justificacion": "101",
"objetivoG": "10",
"objetivoE": "10",
"tags": "100",
"status": 0,
"user_id": 1,
"profe_id": null,
"created_at": "2018-03-30 16:14:29",
"updated_at": "2018-03-30 16:14:29"
},
{
"id": 11,
"titulo": "11",
"antecedentes": "1111",
"problematica": "111",
"justificacion": "111",
"objetivoG": "111",
"objetivoE": "111",
"tags": "1111",
"status": 0,
"user_id": 1,
"profe_id": null,
"created_at": "2018-03-30 16:32:00",
"updated_at": "2018-03-30 16:32:00"
},
{
"id": 12,
"titulo": "12",
"antecedentes": "12",
"problematica": "12",
"justificacion": "12",
"objetivoG": "12",
"objetivoE": "12",
"tags": "12",
"status": 0,
"user_id": 1,
"profe_id": null,
"created_at": "2018-03-30 16:32:28",
"updated_at": "2018-03-30 16:32:28"
},
{
"id": 13,
"titulo": "15",
"antecedentes": "fghfg",
"problematica": "ghfgh",
"justificacion": "hfghf",
"objetivoG": "ghfgh",
"objetivoE": "fghfg",
"tags": "hfghhg",
"status": 0,
"user_id": 1,
"profe_id": null,
"created_at": "2018-03-30 16:33:47",
"updated_at": "2018-03-30 16:33:47"
}
```

mi ruta es esta que he puesto en mi archivo(rutas)

```
Route::resource('projects','proyectoscontroler');
```

---- mis rutas Route list

```html
        | POST      | projects                      | projects.store   | App\Http\Controllers\proyectoscontroler@store                          | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | projects                      | projects.index   | App\Http\Controllers\proyectoscontroler@index                          | web,auth     |
```

de esta forma es mi consulta, para que me regrese los valores

```html
 public function show($id)
    {
    return  Proyecto::where('user_id','=',auth()->user()->id)->get();
    }
```

.... Estuve leyendo ya más acerca de esto, ¿Esto no es otro tema más por así decirlo? proteger mi rutas con Tokens?. Si hay alguna u otra forma pues bienvenida sea.

Estoy trabajando con laravel

Comment: muestra el código donde declaras tus rutas

Comment: ¿Entonces?.  bueno es que si quito show ahora no me cargan mis proyectos :(

Comment: @ShadowPaz ya se cual es el problema de hecho aunque yo ponga en la url 

http://blissre.test/projects/(CUALQUIERCOSA)

Acede  y me muestra todo, Esto es porque 

en show hago esto

 return Proyecto::where('user_id','=',auth()->user()->id)->get();

osea no importa cual ID se envie, siempre va ser mi Id y me va mostrar todo

entonces ahora¿?- como puedo Enviarle mi ID a vue o Axios cuando cargue por primera vez mi pagina de 
 
http://blissre.test/projects como le puedo hacer que enviarle mi  ID Y  se la pase al metodo   de axios ya que en mi codigo en la aprte de Created se ejcuta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es una forma de "proteger" las rutas, pero teniendo en cuenta que utilizas axios, yo entregaría los datos solo para solicitudes ajax, inyectando el request en el método y utilizando el método ajax() para verificar el tipo de solicitud:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        // mostrar o entregar resultados
    } else {
        return 'No se puede mostrar el resultado.'
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, hasta ahorita así lo he dejado.  aunque si voy a checar esos temas de las rutas más adelante.